# How Can I add border on every page of PDF file using Wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: c#, vb.net, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to convert html to pdf using wkhtmltopdf and I have done with it.But I din found any property to add page border in every page .Is there any solution to add page border on every page in Pdf file??

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean just like a single color border around the page, touching the edges of the paper? This is very, very difficult with wkhtmltopdf, I would not use it do something like this. Maybe generate the file and "stamp" the borders with a different tool, for example iText (or iTextSharp seeing that you have a .net project) http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=119

There's this question of SO: [wkhtmltopdf with full page background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057781) which basically deals with your issue - trying to set a full page background, which is similar to what you are trying to achieve. You can evaluate the answers, but I think that it's not really an exact science or a reliable method to twist wkhtmltopdf into doing this.

Comment: Downvoters: It's cool if you do downvote, but I'd love a comment if this has changed or why it's wrong! Thanks